# Pandas: calculating mean value of multiple columns using datetime and Grouper removes columns or doesn't return correct Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

As part of a larger task, I want to calculate the monthly mean values for each specific station. This is already difficult to do, but I am getting close.

The dataframe has many columns, but ultimately I only use the following information:

```
        Date        Value        Station_Name
0       2006-01-03  18           2
1       2006-01-04  12           2
2       2006-01-05  11           2
3       2006-01-06  10           2
4       2006-01-09  22           2
...     ...     ...
3510    2006-12-23  47           45
3511    2006-12-24  46           45
3512    2006-12-26  35           45
3513    2006-12-27  35           45
3514    2006-12-30  28           45
```

I am running into two issues, using:

```
df.groupby(['Station_Name', pd.Grouper(freq='M')])['Value'].mean()
```

It results in something like:

```
Station_Name  Date
2             2003-01-31         29.448387
              2003-02-28         30.617857
              2003-03-31         28.758065
              2003-04-30         28.392593
              2003-05-31         30.318519
                                    ...    
45            2003-09-30         16.160000
              2003-10-31         18.906452
              2003-11-30         26.296667
              2003-12-31         30.306667
              2004-01-31         29.330000
```

Which I can't seem to use as a regular dataframe, and the datetime is messed up as it doesn't show the monthly mean but gives the last day back. Also the station name is a single index, and not for the whole column. Plus the mean value doesn't have a "column name" at all. This isn't a dataframe, but a pandas.core.series.Series. I can't convert this again because it's not correct, and using the .to_frame() method shows that it is still indeed a Dataframe. I don't get this part.

I found that in order to return a normal dataframe, to use

```
as_index = False
```

In the groupby method. But this results in the months not being shown:

```
df.groupby(['station_name', pd.Grouper(freq='M')], as_index = False)['Value'].mean()
```

Gives:

```
   Station_Name          Value
0             2      29.448387
1             2      30.617857
2             2      28.758065
3             2      28.392593
4             2      30.318519
... ... ...
142          45      16.160000
143          45      18.906452
144          45      26.296667
145          45      30.306667
146          45      29.330000
```

I can't just simply add the month later, as not every station has an observation in every month.

I've tried using other methods, such as

```
df.resample("M").mean()
```

But it doesn't seem possible to do this on multiple columns. It returns the mean value of everything.

Edit: This is ultimately what I would want.

```
   Station_Name      Date               Value
0             2   2003-01           29.448387
1             2   2003-02           30.617857
2             2   2003-03           28.758065
3             2   2003-04           28.392593
4             2   2003-05           30.318519
... ... ...
142          45   2003-08           16.160000
143          45   2003-09           18.906452
144          45   2003-10           26.296667
145          45   2003-11           30.306667
146          45   2003-12           29.330000
```

Comment: That is true, but that is the least of my concerns now.I can't seem to get it to work properly in general.

Comment: I added what I want my outcome to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , how baout this :

```
df = df.groupby(['Station_Name',df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')])['Value'].mean().reset_index()
```

outut:

```
>>
   Station_Name     Date  Value
0             2  2006-01   14.6
1            45  2006-12   38.2
```

Comment: Hmm when I run this I'm getting: KeyError "Date". I found a way to do it in the end, but I'd prefer a one-line solution.

Comment: I think it's an issue with pandas during conversion to datetime, it stays as an object in python, not a datetime format. I'll be able to use this for this issue, but will open another question for the rest. Thanks!

Comment: Is your date column of date time type?

Comment: It was when reading in, but apparently applying a format before converted the column to an object, not a datetime anymore. I posted a new question about this and it seems that this is an issue from before. Thanks.